# WSGI error using Django 2.2 on Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: django, mod-wsgi, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Trying to access a Django 2.2 web app deployed to AWS Elastic Beanstalk gives a 500 error. When checking the elastic beanstalk logs the below errors are shown.

```
 mod_wsgi (pid=3388): Target WSGI script '/opt/python/current/app/app_name/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
 mod_wsgi (pid=3388): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/opt/python/current/app/app_name/wsgi.py'.
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/opt/python/current/app/app_name/wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>
     application = get_wsgi_application()
   File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 12, in get_wsgi_application
     django.setup(set_prefix=False)
   File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
     apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
   File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 83, in populate
     raise RuntimeError("populate() isn't reentrant")
 RuntimeError: populate() isn't reentrant
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because Django 2.2 is not (as of this writing) compatible with EB.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create-deploy-python-django.html

> Django 2.2 is incompatible with the Elastic Beanstalk Python 3.6
>   platform. The latest compatible version is Django 2.1.

Comment: Do you have any links to sources explaining further? What is special about Beanstalk's version of Python 3.6?

Comment: Unsure, I couldn't find anything else from Amazon explaining it. I downgraded to django 2.1 and the issue is resolved.

Comment: Has this changed? I deployed an app a few months ago with Django version 3.0.5 and it works perfectly. I created a new app now and it gives me the same error for Django versions higher than 2.1 now.